# Ionic using back button with out a top menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a specific page that I want full screen, so I hide the top bar and have a custom back button that calls `ionicNavBarDelegate.back()`, it does nothing. I even tried to call the parent controllers `ionicNavBarDelegate.back()` with an event, with no success. I can make it go back using javascript but then the history gets all messed up. It's basically trying to have back button on pages with out a top menu. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Before calling $ionicNavBarDelegate.back() try checking if there even is a backStack with $ionicViewService.getBackView())

Comment: I will check that. I know it worked before when I had the top nav bar. Does calling `hide-nav-bar="true"` on the `ion-view` delete the history?